# How to get start and end Datetime of ISO 8601 week in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, iso

If I have the Year (say 2013) and the ISO week (say 35), how do I get the Starting and Ending DateTime in pure JavaScript?

Is there any specific Library for dealing with DateTime in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as a library, there is http://www.datejs.com/  . Or http://phpjs.org/functions/date/ .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var date  = new Date('01 Jan ' + year);
date.setDate(35 * 7);
date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay()) //it will give the start of the week
```

Comment: This doesn't give ISO week. Try it for 2009, 1st week. That should begin on 2008/12/29